# evaluating button clicks java

Tags: java, swing

I have the following code:

```
for (int i = 0; i < dynamicVariable; i++) {
    String tmpString = myArray[i];
    JToggleButton tButton = new JToggleButton(tmpString);
    myJPanel.add(tButton);
    tButton.addActionListener(this);
}
JButton go = new JButton("go");
myJPanel.add(submit);
```

Where I create x amount of buttons and add them to my panel. What I now need to do is, when the user selects the correct buttons and hits go. I evaluate all the selected buttons. If they are all right, then print `true`, otherwise print `false`. If they select all the correct answers except one, then it should evaluate to `false`. I just have no idea how to evaluate each button selected inside the `actionPerformed()` method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should first map the correct values for each button, then if the user clicks on the *Go* button, then iterate over the buttons, checking for each button if it is correctly toggled on or off.

In short:

- First we define the correct answers as a map with each toggle button bound to a boolean indicating whether the statement is correct or not;
- Then we add all toggle buttons to the panel;
- Then we add a listener to the *Go* button, which determines whether the selected button is correctly pressed or left unpressed.

Here's the code:

```
// Put all values into a map. If the mentioned fruit has the mentioned
// color, then the answer is correct.
private Map<JToggleButton, Boolean> correctAnswers = new HashMap<JToggleButton, Boolean>() {{
    put(new JToggleButton("A strawberry is red"), true);
    put(new JToggleButton("A banana is blue"), false);
    put(new JToggleButton("A lemon is yellow"), true);
    put(new JToggleButton("An orange is orange"), true);
}};

void init() {
    for (JToggleButton button : map.keySet()) {
        // button.setActionListener(this); // The toggle buttons themselves
        // do not need to have a listener, do they? Only when the user clicks
        // "go", then the buttons should be evaluated, right?
        myJPanel.add(button);
    }
    JButton submitButton = new JButton("go");
    submitButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
            boolean wrong = false; // It's all good now, until a wrong
            // answer is found.

            // Iterate over all entries of our map.
            for (JToggleButton button : this.buttons.keySet()) {
                // Check if the selection state of the toggle button is
                // equal to whether the answer is yes or no.
                if (button.isSelected() != this.buttons.get(button)) {
                    // A button is pressed while it should not be pressed
                    // OR vice versa. Let's mark that at least one button
                    // is incorrect.
                    wrong = true;
                }
            }

            // We found at least one incorrect button.
            if (wrong) {
                // DO SOMETHING
            }
        }
    });
    myJPanel.add(submitButton);
}
```

*I haven't tested this code, but it should work.*

Comment: using ideas from both answers I have this code http://pastebin.com/Jy82WqkG I have two questions, is this code on the right track? if yes what I now need to do is that if ever a button clicked is false the boolean will always stay false

Answer (score 2):

Put all the buttons into a `List` or array, then iterate over this when the `go` button is clicked

```
private List<JToggleButton> listOfButtons;
//...
listOfButtons = new ArrayList<>(dynamicVariable);
for (int i=0; i<dynamicVariable;i++){
    String tmpString= myArray[i];
    JToggleButton  tButton = new JToggleButton (tmpString);
    listOfButtons.add(tButton);
    myJPanel.add(tButton);
    tButton.addActionListener(this);
}
JButton go= new JButton("go");
myJPanel.add(submit);
//...

// ActionListener of go button
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
    for (JToggleButton btn : listOfButtons) {
        if (btn.isSelected()) {
            // Evaluate the state, set some flags
            // get funky tonight
        }
    }
    // Evaluate the final state once you know what
    // buttons are actually selected
}
```

Comment: adding to an array wouldn't work would it? I need to check which buttons are selected once i hit go, this just adds the buttons to an array

Comment: Sorry, see update. Once you have the buttons in a `List` or array, then you can use that `List` or array to simply iterate over at some time in the future (assuming you make that `List` or array an instance field, which is implied in the example)